# How can i get Frame rate, Bitrate of any video file(wmv,mov,H.264,mp4)

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

i need to fetch the informations like frame per second, Bitrate for video file (wmv,mov,H.264,mp4) i m using IMediaDet for getting informations, it working fine for wmv, avi but not for mov and H264, and i am using ffddow codec for playing the mov and other file.

Is there any other way to find these information using DirectShow or any other api.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will be hard to find one API or something in DirectShow which can tackle various different formats. I would suggest to call

```
ffmpeg -i filename
```

and parse the output in order to get the desired informations.